# WPF Label Content binding to Subproperty

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm still relatively new to WPF and am having difficulty with bindings.  I am attempting to bind a label content to the property of an object property.  I've tried several methods with this being the latest version.  The update to the property occurs when the instance of the object is constructed.  So far, I don't see the updates when the new instance is created and assigned.

The Class:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _name As String

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
            OnPropertyValueChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberNameAttribute> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Window:

```
Public Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window

    Public Property Instance As TestClass

    Private Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
       Instance = New TestClass()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Test Form" 
Height="499" 
Width="667"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Instance.Name}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the property no longer updates is because you are not notifying the UI that `Instance` has changed.  One way to fix this would be to create a `DependencyProperty` in your `MainWindow` like this.

```
Public Property Instance As TestClass
    Get
        Return GetValue(InstanceProperty)
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As TestClass)
        SetValue(InstanceProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly InstanceProperty As DependencyProperty = _
                       DependencyProperty.Register("Instance", _
                       GetType(TestClass), GetType(MainWindow), _
                       New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))
```

This would replace your current property.  Your button click code would remain the same.  The `DependencyProperty` handles notifications so you do not need to explicitly call `OnPropertyChanged`.

On a side note, you may want to look into Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern if you are still learning as that seems to be the common `WPF` pattern.